# What is a graph called with no "hanging" nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

I have this graph $G$, that I'll represent first by the matrix $C$ which will show which vertices are connected to which where $0$ represents that the vertices are not connected, $1$ represents that the vertices are connected, and $\eta$ represents the vertex itself (which is to say $C_{i,i} = \eta$ for all $i$). Thus, here is $C$
$$ C = \begin{pmatrix} \eta & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & \eta & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & \eta & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \eta
\end{pmatrix}$$
Alternatively, this can be represented as such
\begin{align*}
1 &\leftrightarrow 2 \\
2 &\leftrightarrow 3 \\
3 &\leftrightarrow 4 \\
4 &\leftrightarrow 1
\end{align*}

The graph visually looks like this

[image]

I was trying to search for its name and thought that it would be called a "Closed Graph", but all I found was the Closed Graph Theorem which did not seem relevant to this. Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm just wondering what a graph with all the vertices connected like this would be called.

Comment: No vertices of degree $1$/no leaves?

Comment: Yes. Additionally, all vertices of degree 2.

Comment: If all vertices have degree $2$, perhaps a regular graph?

Comment: So would I be correct in calling this a 2-regular, connected graph?

Comment: I believe that is what you're describing.  See if the definition fits.

Comment: You can call it a "circular graph" or more properly, a cycle of length 4: $C_4$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph.